# Audit Resilience4j HTTP response status codes

Tags: spring, feign, resilience4j

In present situation I can write in DB only result

- true - is good
- false - is bad

How can I get http code and analyze it?

*For example, if response code is 204 or 400 for me it's good response. All others are bad... And write it to DB.*

Now I'm reading about ErrorDecoder (in Feign), am I looking in the right direction?
But I would not want to change the logic of ALL FeignClient, only one method

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestService {

  private final DataBaseService dataBaseService;
  private final TestRepository testRepository;
  private final TestFeign testFeign;

  @Async
  @Retry(name = "testRetry", fallbackMethod = "testFallback")
  public void rboLimitComplexSetting(UUID uuid, TestRequest testRequest) {
    log.info("Отправка запроса в RBO limitId = {} ", limitId);
    testFeign.test(testRequest);
    addLog(uuid, true);
  }

  private void testFallback(UUID uuid, TestRequest testRequest, RuntimeException ex) {
    addLog(limitId, false);
  }

  private void addLog(UUID uuid, boolean result) {
    var entity = dataBaseService.findById(uuid);
    entity.setResult(result);

    testRepository.save(entity);
  }
}
```